# Filtering out multiple items

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter out a large number of items from a list. I have about 500 keys to filter out of an input list of 700. I don't know if there's a list item for each key though, so the "dumb" approach I went down was to loop through each key comparing it to each row of the input list. The code I've written technically works, but it's not efficient and crashes as soon as I try testing with too many keys. Is there a more elegant solution?

My attempt:

```
Sub ExcludeKeys()

'Copy input to new output sheet
Dim outputTabName As String
Worksheets("Input").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
outputTabName = "Output " + Strings.Trim(Worksheets.Count - 3)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = outputTabName

'Get the column letter the keys are in (input data)
Dim keyCol As String
keyCol = Strings.Trim(Worksheets("Home").Range("D17").Value)

Dim row As Range
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim keyToEval As Variant

'Make an array out of existing keys
totalKeys = Worksheets("Keys").Rows.End(xlUp).row

'Go through the Output sheet
For rowNum = 2 To Worksheets(outputTabName).Rows.Count

    'Go through all keys to exclude
    For i = 1 To LastRow(Worksheets("Keys").Name, 1)

        'Get new key to compare to (in output)
        keyToEval = Strings.Trim(Worksheets(outputTabName).Range(keyCol & rowNum).Value)

        'If keys match, delete
        If keyToEval = Strings.Trim(Worksheets("Keys").Range("A" & i).Value) Then
            Worksheets(outputTabName).Range(keyCol & rowNum).Rows.EntireRow.Delete
            'If a row was deleted, go back 1 (avoids skipping next)
            i = 1
        End If
    Next i
Next rowNum

End Sub

'----------
' Handy function to find the last row of a column
' Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504852/4984516
Function LastRow(Optional strSheet As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet As Worksheet

    If strSheet = vbNullString Then
       Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(strSheet)
    End If

    LastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).row

End Function
```

Comment: You could use COUNTIF or MATCH formula and then autofilter. Quicker than looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, but I figured out a better way to do it. This is essentially a macro version of the Advanced Filter button. I copied the Input tab to Output, which I then work on as following:

```
Dim keyCount As Long
keyCount = Sheets("Keys").Cells(Sheets("Keys").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Worksheets("Output").Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=_
    xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=_
    Sheets("Keys").Range("A1:A" & keyCount), Unique:=False
```

No need for loops and very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same types (integer, string) then i would put both of your lists into a List(of) and then use the Except function.  this will return you a list of all items that are not present in the original list.  This doesnt modify either list.

```
var remainingItems = FullList.Except(excludeList);
```

Comment: Don't think that is a VBA function?